# Kotlin make array of selected items

Tags: android, kotlin

I have multiple select option and I can receive their ids **what I need is to make array of those ids** in order to send them to server.

**Why I want to make array of my array?**

Because my main array includes other information and I just need to extract (make array) of ids not any other values such as names.

#### Example

I will select 2 items and I receive

```
id->1
name->one

id->2
name->two
```

Then I just need to make array like:

```
items[
    0->1
    1->2
]
```

#### Code

```
private fun printSelectedValue() {
  serviceAdapter?.getList()?.let {
    it.forEach { service ->
      Log.e("printSelectedValue", "selected service name:- ${service.service.name}")

      // I need array of this (service.id)
      Log.e("printSelectedValue", "selected service id:- ${service.id}")
    }
  }
}
```

> PS: I need to be able to use this array (array of ids) in another function so it's preferred to have private value in my fragment in order to access it in other function

**Any idea?**

Comment: If you need only array of id declare an `ArrayList` globally. Populate that ArrayList from selected items' array.

Comment: @Kaushik that's the thing, I don't know how? I'm still newbie in this

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
fun getSelectedIds(): Map<Int, Int> {
  val items = serviceAdapter?.getList() ?: return
  return items.withIndex().associate { (index, item) -> index to item.id }
}
```

Comment: how do i access it in other function? what is global value in this fragment?

Comment: just make it is a function

Comment: My code is already inside function so I've created `private lateinit var selectedServices: ArrayList<String?>` then I wrote `val selectedIds = it.map { it.id }
            selectedServices = selectedIds as ArrayList<String?>` does that make sense?

Comment: I think should call `getSelectedIds` when needed instead of storing a var

Comment: Sorry to take back my accept but error isn't solved yet :(

Comment: I need to send array of ids to server and there is no way I can get this array. as I mentioned i need my array to be like `items[
    0->1
    1->2
]`

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving you an example, change this code according to your use case

In your data class add an extra field for detecting the item is selected or not
so your data class should look like this

```
data class Item(val id: Int, val name: String, var isSelected: Boolean)
```

While selecting deselecting item change the value of `isSelected` accordingly.
Then before sending the value populate an empty ArrayList from selected ArrayList like this

```
val selectedList = actualDataSet.filter { it.isSelected }
var ids = ArrayList<Int>()
selectedList.forEach { service ->
     ids.add(service.id) 
}
//here you will get the ArrayList of selected items' id
```

Comment: Is `var ids = ArrayList<Int>()` a global variable? Like lateinit?

Comment: yes you can declare it in global scope or you can create it whenever you want to send the data to server if you declare it globally **don't forget to clear the list before populating new data**

Comment: Ok thanks, later today I will test your solution. Thank you for your time

Comment: Hi, when I do ` lateinit var ids: ArrayList<Int>()` it says `Property getter or setter expected` inside `()`

Comment: don't use lateinit just do `var ids = ArrayList<Int>()`